# npm ERR! missing script: android

Tags: react-native

I get several npm ERR! when trying to run : D:\React Native\cleanProject>npm run android
npm ERR! missing script: android

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-03-26T08_39_44_164Z-debug.log

npm i

D:\React Native\cleanProject>npm run android
npm ERR! missing script: android

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-03-26T08_39_44_164Z-debug.log

Answer (score 4):

The command that you are trying to run is doesn't exist. Please try to run with this given below command.

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: 'react-native' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: Do `npm install` in the project directory and then run again `react-native run-android`

Comment: error: unknown command 'run-android'

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to run the following command for installing 'react-native' project to your Node JS first.

```
npm install react-native
```

After that, also make sure an *emulator* is started or *cell phone* is connected with developer mode.

And then retry by running

```
react-native run-android
```

to see if you can build and run the your application successfully.

Answer (score 0):

check if your environment variable set properly.

In your PATH Variable:

C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
C:\Program Files\nodejs

In your system Variable
ANDROID_HOME C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191

Hope it works...

Answer (score 0):

Follow this command, it works for me

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are in the root directory of your app before using react-native run-android

1- open your project and make sure you see the android rectory 
2- in the address bar at the top type cmd and a new cmd will open at that location
3- type react-native run-android

I hope it helps